# Slice vs type alias as the method receiver

Tags: go, methods, types

I have a struct `Foo` with a method `print`:

```golang
type Foo struct {
    Bar string
}
func (f Foo) print() {
    fmt.Println(f.Bar)
}
```

If I want to print for a slice of `Foo`, the canonical way perhaps is to write a `for` loop, and have a function to encapsulate it:

```golang
func printFoos(fs []Foo) {
    for _, f := range fs {
        f.print()
    }
}
printFoos([]Foo{})
```

Coming from an OOP background, I find this approach a bit unappealing.

What I would like to do is to associate `printFoos` with `[]Foo`:

```golang
// Invalid Go code
func (fs []Foo) print() {
    for _, f := range fs {
        f.print()
    }
}
```

The above doesn't work because in Go, an unnamed type can't be used as the method receiver, as discussed in [this Google Group thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/mcQSM-yTizA/5RqYJ_kFnEUJ).

To circumvent it, it is possible to write:

```golang
type Foos []Foo
func (fs Foos) print() {
    for _, f := range fs {
        f.print()
    }
}
```

To use it, I have to explicitly declare the type as `Foos`, so still I can't use `print` on `[]Foo`

```golang
fs := []Foo{}
fs.print() // error
var fss Foos = fs
fss.print()
```

What I'm confused about is, in the above code, `fss` and `fs` are clearly of the same type, as I can assign `fs` to `fss` without error. However, we can't simply use `fs.print()` and let Go be smart about the conversion.

**Why is this the case?**

The full code can be found on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lYniODJPJ2I).

Comment: Because `print` is declared on `Foos`, not on `[]Foo`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What I'm confused about is, in the above code, `fss` and `fs` are clearly of the same type, as I can assign `fs` to `fss` without error.

You jump to the wrong conclusion. Having the same type is not a must have requirement for [assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability).

`fss` has type `Foos`, and `fs` has type `[]Foo`, an unnamed slice type. It's true that they have the same underlying type, that's why you can assign `fs` to `fss`, covered in this assignability rule:

> A value `x` is *assignable* to a [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> - ...
> - `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical [underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a [defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) type.

Methods are bound to concrete types. So the `Foos.print()` method is not available for a value of a different type, including `[]Foo`.

But you don't need to create a variable just to call that method, you may simply use a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
Foos(fs).print()
```

This conversion does not change the memory layout, just the type, so it's safe and efficient. We used it only to gain access to a method of a type with identical underlying type.

Comment: What is meant by *at least one of `V` or `T` is not a defined type*? Aren't both types defined? IOW, `type Foos Foo[]` is also a defined type.

Comment: @Shuzheng `Foos` is a defined type, but the parameter of `printFoos(fs []Foo)`, here type of `fs` is `[]Foo`, it is **not** a defined type. This means a type of `Foos` is assignable to a variable of type `[]Foo` and thus passable as the argument for `fs`, because the assignability rule applies (_"at least one of `V` or `T` is not a defined type"_ – `[]Foo` is not a defined type).